# Error Database back up in centos

Tags: centos

I try to run `pg_dump` on CentOS 6 but some error occur:

> error while loading shared libraries: liblber-2.3.so.0: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

I already ran `#yum install compat-openldap` but that error still happens.

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Try to see if this is not a 32bits 64bits library version issue (eg: try to install the other xxbits version of the library).

Comment: the library was installed is for both bit sir.